# Can you influence Windows 10 to not force devices into "Unspecified" device category?

Tags: windows, drivers, operating-systems

Windows 10 forces Motherboard relatd hardware to be shown in "Unspecified" device category.
Is it possible to influence OS in a way to not show a device under that category or hide the category itself in Devices/Printers view?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to influence OS in a way to not show a device under
> that category or hide the category itself in Devices/Printers view?

No.  Devices show up as unspecified because they are not certified for Windows 10.

Unspecified devices are not new, but Windows 10 has been more rigorous.

You can ask the device manufacturer (support site) if they have a more up to date and certified driver.

Comment: The drivers are shown as very old indeed. They are from 2006 and shows input.inf as Outranked Drivers. It's a modern B550 GIGABYTE Board.

Comment: 2006 precedes Windows 10 by several years, so probably not much you can do in this case.

Comment: @atereou - John made no mention of your motherboard.  There is little to no chance the device is on a B550 motherboard. A motherboard released in 2020 is not going to have any device drivers from 16 years ago.